# Measure the Length of a Line on a Map after a MOUSE_MOVE Event

Tags: apache-flex, api, actionscript, mouseevent, esri

One of the actions a user can perform using the ESRI Flex Viewer application is to draw a shape on a map (e.g. a line). Once the user is finished drawing the line, they will double-click the mouse which fires a DrawEvent.DRAW_END event.  When this is fired, the line is measured using a call to an API function `geometryService.project([geometryObject], spatialReference);`.

I want to be able to call this function after a MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE event in order to measure the line on the fly, instead of only after the DRAW_END event.  Unfortunately, the only two DrawEvents that get dispatched are the DrawEvent.DRAW_START and DrawEvent.DRAW_END.  These ESRI classes are compiled classes, so I cannot make any changes to them.

Is there a way to add an eventListener to a MOUSE_MOVE event that can grab the current geometry of the line that is being drawn and call my API function to measure on the fly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, ESRI is a company that specializes in GIS (Geographic Information Systems) applications.  They make software like ArcGIS that is fairly ubiquitous nowadays.  They also provide nice APIs so that users can write custom applications that use their services, like the one I'm writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem by circumventing the geometry service altogether and building a solution of my own.  There is a [great site](http://thunderhead.esri.com/readonlyurl/Utils.as) that implements the Vincenty algorithm for measuring the distance between two coordinates.  This is a very accurate approximation algorithm (within .5mm on Vincenty's earth ellipsoid), and is meant to be very efficient so that it can be used frequently (e.g. after a mouse moves).

Here's the basic steps to implement this:

1. Add an event listener to the map that listens for a mouse click
2. Once the mouse is clicked, convert the coordinates of the location of the click on the screen to map coordinates and add a listener to watch for a mouse move event
3. When the mouse moves, grab the coordinates of the mouse (as in step 2) and perform the Vincenty calculation.  Create a custom tooltip on the map and add the Vincenty result to the tooltip text.
4. Upon double-click, send the result to the Geometry service and remove the tooltip from the map